# Cloudflare Firewall rules not working as expected

Tags: cloudflare

I have a firewall rule to block all traffic to my site except from my country. What is weird is that I can access example.com but [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is blocked even in my own country. How can I solve this please
My F/W rule looks like this

```
(ip.geoip.country ne "XX") or (ip.geoip.country ne "XY") or (not cf.client.bot) or (http.host ne "example.com") or (http.host ne "www.example.com")
```

(note XX and XY are my 2 countries that I need to allow traffic from e.g US for United States).
The issue is my geoip data shows I'm in country XX but I get blocked when accessing `https://www.example.com` but `https://example.com` works fine. Can someone help me out on this please?

Comment: Is this an allow rule or a block rule?  Either way, I believe the logic is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This logic is not correct for a blocking rule, but I cannot explain why it is working for www only. Here is my best guess at the blocking rule that you need:

```
# if client is a known bot OR client is not one of these two countries OR host is not in one of these two hosts
(cf.client.bot) or (not ip.geoip.country in {"XX" "XY"}) or (not http.host in {"www.example.com" "example.com"})
```